# ASP WebForms re-evaluate property on post back

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Basically I want to set the default date on a jQuery calendar.  I have a little script that runs fine when the page loads.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var calendarPicker = $('input[name="ctl00$MainContent$ucDetails$LeftPanel$fieldDate$dateValue$calendarPicker"]');

        if (calendarPicker.val() == "") {
            calendarPicker.datepicker("option", "defaultDate", '<%# CalendarDefaultDate %>');
        }
    });
</script>
```

However, when the user changes the value on a combo box, the page posts back and runs some code which causes the value of `CalendarDefaultDate` to update.  The problem is that even though the value of the property has changed, it doesn't get reflected on the page.

Any ideas how to fix this? Many thanks.

Update 1.  Tried using the ClientScriptManager as advised. (with no joy)

```
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.AppendLine("$(function(){var calendarPicker = $(\"input[name='ctl00$MainContent$ucDetails$LeftPanel$fieldDate$dateValue$calendarPicker']\")");
        builder.AppendLine("if (calendarPicker.val() == '') {");
        builder.AppendLine("calendarPicker.datepicker(\"option\", \"defaultDate\", '" + CalendarDefaultDate + "')");
        builder.AppendLine("}});");

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "CalenderDefaultDate", builder.ToString(), true);
```

Comment: Also are you using partial Update with Ajax?

Comment: Is this CalendarDefaultDate is public string variable of your page class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ClientScriptManager to run your function on the reload:

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AKey", "MyFunction();", true);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx

Try to declare your function on aspx file this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function assignCalendar () {

        var calendarPicker = $('input[name="ctl00$MainContent$ucDetails$LeftPanel$fieldDate$dateValue$calendarPicker"]');

        if (calendarPicker.val() == "") {
            calendarPicker.datepicker("option", "defaultDate", '<%# CalendarDefaultDate %>');
        }
    };
</script>
```

Then in code behind call it like below:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "assignCalendar ", "<script type='text/javascript'>assignCalendar();</script>", false);
```

If you put it on PageLoad event i think it will work

Comment: I tried this fix but doesn't seem to be working :(               Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "CalenderDefaultDate", builder.ToString(), true);

Comment: Thanks for the update... I tried your fix exactly as described with no joy :(

Comment: with a lot of messing about and frustration I did get this working.